# SharePoint Full Crawl Times

Tags: search, central-administration, crawl

I'm currently doing a Full Crawl on my SharePoint server. It's been running for about 5 hours. It's adding items to the 'success' column of the crawl History.

This is after doing an Index reset, and it's the first Full Crawl on this site.

My question: Is this normal? Should I stop the crawl?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured any crawler impact rules?

Comment: I have not set any crawler impact rules. This I will look into. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The performance of search will depend on a few things

Size of target being crawled, bigger it is the longer it'll take, naturally. Also, the performance of the target, if pages are loading slowly, search will run slower.

Your farm infrastructure: services per server and server performance. How is your farm setup? Is search running on its own server or shared with other services? How many users are actively on your sites? What's the hardware specs of the servers running search? These are some of the considerations for performance of search.

I'd recommend running a full crawl when user traffic is lowest, and server resources are most available, usually late night, early morning, not during a system backup.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the input! The farm is very small, one DB server, and one App server with maybe 3 users at any one time. I'm still developing this thing so I haven't rolled it out to the entire group. I recently moved the DB off of the app server and onto a DB server. I didn't move any of the databases except for the content database, I re-installed SharePoint then attached the content database. I've been having issues with search authenticating and on Friday finally nailed it, I opted to reset the Index before doing a full crawl to "start fresh" The content Database is very small still..

Comment: Yes, my full crawl lasts about 14 hours. I have to do this on the weekends.

Comment: Thank You, Mike. This is the first time I've got it to successfully crawl everything, so it's going much slower than my previous unsuccessful attempts!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on so many factors. Server configuration, amount of data to index specific settings for the content sources/scopes. Be very careful though when setting your content sources. I once had a client set their search to follow links. They had linked to their internet site and then had links from that to other sites. When they finally asked me to take a look it had been running for 90 hours, they were in the process of indexing Amazon.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't have it set to follow links, just to read complex URLs. It's still crawling along. It may be because the system only has 1 core on 1 CPU in our VM Environment